# Revealing parts of an image in processing with Arduino Uno interface

Tags: java, arduino, processing

I'm currently working on an Arduino Uno and Processing interface with the idea of revealing an image much like a "scratch off lottery ticket." I currently have the image uploaded into the sketch and the black background ready, however I'm not sure at this point how to start revealing the image through fill()

I know that I could technically use an ellipse of 1 pixel wide that will SLOWLY reveal the image (and subsequently take forever because the Arduino joystick isn't very cooperative.) but I was hoping there would be an easier way to reveal it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
void draw() {
  noStroke();
  ellipse(xPos, yPos, 1,1);

  if(zButton == 0){
   background(0);
  }

  color c = img.get(xPos, yPos);

  fill(c);

  serialEvent(myPort);


}
```

This is the draw function, it reads the joystick's interface through the serialEvent function, as of right now I have a 1x1 ellipse revealing the image pixel by pixel, but that would be extremely tedious

Thanks guys, any help is appreciated

Comment: No pastebin, this ain't no forum. Post the code here.

Comment: If you format it decently, you will increase the likelihood that someone will read it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.get(x,y)` to get individual pixels, you can use [loadPixels](https://processing.org/reference/loadPixels_.html) to expose the pixel array, and simply color those instead. This is generally much faster than using the `get` and `set` functions.

To speed things up further, cache the image's pixels and track which consecutive lines you can just [copy](https://processing.org/reference/copy_.html) over (for instance, if you offer a 5 pixel radius ellipse, then you can track the fact that you need to copy 5 pixels starting at position X, which you can then copy over as a single call. The more the user scratches, the more pixels you can copy that way in a single call)